# How can I find the accumulation points of the sequence $a_n=n^2\cos({2n\pi/3})/(1+n^2)\,$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence

Define
$$a_n = \frac{n^2}{1+n^2}\,\cos(\frac{2n\pi}{3}).$$

How can I find this sequence's **accumulation points**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that the cosine term can have only three distinct values for any $n$. Then choose three different sequences: $a_{3n}$, $a_{3n+1}$ and $a_{3n+2}$. Notice that each of those sequences has a different limit. So you will have three accumulation points.

Comment: I did this and found $1, \frac{-1}{2}$ and $\frac{-1}{2}$ again. So accumulation points of this sequence are $1$ and $\frac{-1}{2}$, right?

Comment: Looks right. It will be three distinct points if you have sine instead of cosine

Comment: Thank you so much.